# Create line chart using Google Chart API and JSON for DataTable

Tags: javascript, json, charts, google-visualization

javaI am trying to create a line chart using the Google Chart API. I am trying to set the data using JSON for the datatable via a AJAX post.

I have a version working for the pie chart but I can't find out how to do it for the line chart.

Below is how I am creating the chart with the ajax post.

```
function drawLineGraph()
             {
                 $.post("loadGraph.php",
                    {
                        type: "line"
                    },
                    function (result)
                    {
                        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(result);
                        var options = {
                            title: "Line Graph Test"
                        };

                        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("lineChart"));
                        chart.draw(data, options);
                    }, "json"
                );
             }
```

Below is the code for the loadGraph.php

```
print json_encode(test());

    function test()
    {
        $array = array();
        if ($_POST['type'] == "line")
        {
            $array['cols'][] = array('type' => 'string');
            $array['cols'][] = array('type' => 'number');

            $temp = array();
            $array['row'][] = array('v' => (string) "20-01-13");
            $array['row'][] = array('v' => (int) 35);
            $array['row'][] = array('v' => (string) "21-01-13");
            $array['row'][] = array('v' => (int) 30);

        }
}
```

Although no errors occur, the line chart is sort of displayed, but there is no line, as if the data is 0. Below is a screenshot of how the chart is being displayed

[image: Line chart not working]

Below is the output of the JSON content.

```
{"cols":[{"type":"string"},{"type":"number"}],"row":[{"c":[{"v":"20-01-13"},{"v":22}]},{"c":[{"v":"21-01-13"},{"v":24}]},{"c":[{"v":"22-01-13"},{"v":27}]}]}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

**UPDATE**
I have tried to do what @davidkonrad suggested but I am now getting a different problem. I have changed the definition of row to rows for the PHP array as follows:

```
    $array['cols'][] = array('type' => 'string');
    $array['cols'][] = array('type' => 'number');

    $array['rows'][] = array('c' => "20-01-13");
    $array['rows'][] = array('v' => 35);
    $array['rows'][] = array('c' => "21-01-13");
    $array['rows'][] = array('v' => 30);
```

But now when the graph loads I get `Cannot read property '0' of undefined` where the graph should be displayed.

Below is how the JSON is now being generated

```
{"cols":[{"type":"string"},{"type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":"20-01-13"},{"v":35},{"c":"21-01-13"},{"v":30}]}
```

I can't see how to change the array to make it match with the JSON that davidkonrad provided

Comment: Could you please post an example of the JSON data that your PHP generates?

Comment: @SergeyG I have added the JSON output

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is a very small typo. In the JSON, `row` should be `rows`.

Eg, changing the example JSON to

```
var result = { "cols":[ {"type":"string"}, {"type":"number"}], "rows":[ {"c":[{"v":"20-01-13"}, {"v":22}]}, {"c":[{"v":"21-01-13"}, {"v":24}]}, {"c":[{"v":"22-01-13"}, {"v":27}]} ]};
```

and your code works :
[image]

**Update**

Look at [Format of the Constructor's JavaScript Literal data Parameter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam)
You need to wrap each "c"-section into brackets and also misses "v" (value indicator) for the first column.

Your updated test JSON is

```
"cols": [
    {"type":"string"},{"type":"number"}
        ],
"rows":[
    {"c":"20-01-13"},{"v":35},
    {"c":"21-01-13"},{"v":30}
        ]
}
```

giving a "can't read 0 of undefined", becuase it should be

```
{
"cols":[
    {"type":"string"},{"type":"number"}
    ],
"rows":[
    {"c": [{ "v": "20-01-13"},{"v":35} ]},
    {"c": [{ "v": "21-01-13"},{"v":30} ]}
    ]
}
```

graph :

[image]

Hope it helps!

**Absolutely final update**

Modified PHP that along with `json_encode` outputs data in the correct google chart format :

```
function test() {
    $array = array();

    $array['cols'][] = array('type' => 'string');
    $array['cols'][] = array('type' => 'number');

    //HERE you have the difference
    $array['rows'][]['c'] = array(
        array('v' => "20-01-13"),
        array('v' => 35)
    );
    $array['rows'][]['c'] = array(
        array('v' => "21-01-13"),
        array('v' => 30)
    );

    return json_encode($array);
}
```

outputs

```
{"cols":[{"type":"string"},{"type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"20-01-13"},{"v":35}]},{"c":[{"v":"21-01-13"},{"v":30}]}]}
```

which leads to the graph above

Comment: thanks for the help, I've tried changing the PHP array before the encoding to make it ``rows`` instead of ``row`` but I am getting a slightly different error now. Instead the graph now says that it can't read 0 of undefined where the graph should. I have updated the question to include the changes I've made based on your answer

Comment: Updated answer, hope it helps

Comment: I understand that the JSON isn't correct, but its building the array in the PHP so that when the array is passed through json_encode it comes out in the correct format.

Comment: Yeah, of course it is the PHP that should be corrected :-) Thought the problem (for you) was the syntax for google charts iself. Above a modified version of the test() function that produces correct JSON google charts is able to parse.

Comment: Yea it was the PHP I was asking about, but thanks it is working now. Much appreciated